Debug unexpected results when using a spatial join to determine if a point is in a set of districts
I am making a map of lead violations in New York City per building. I am attempting to aggregate the buildings with violations and violations by districts that are not currently not available in NYC Open Data (specifically state senate and state assembly district) by spatial joining the coordinates of buildings with various district geometries. However, when I test my results using spatial joining with city council district geometries and compare it to per council district data from NYC Open Data, the results are mismatched, and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
Here is my process:
I am pulling the data from NYC Open Data HPD Violations table and storing the data in two different tables:Buildings for each unique building in the violation list and then a violations table with a foreign key to a building.
I pulled the long and lat of the building from NYC Open Data with an SRID of 4326. I soon realized the long lat is just an estimate according to the data dictionary for that table. So I turned to version 2 of the NYC Geocoding API.
After seeding the database with building info, I submit the Building Identification Number (or address where I don't have the BIN) to get the longitudeInternalLabel and latitudeInternalLabel, which is suppose to be the most accurate.
For the district maps, I downloaded the clipped-to-shores versions of the various maps, I uploaded them to mapshaper, project them at wgs84, simplified them down to 5% and made sure to avoid removing shapes and then export as geojson.
I then seed tables for the district by looping through each geometry and storing it in a polygon or multipolygon column with projection 4326.
However, when I compare the aggregate results to NYC Open data, the numbers are closer but still far off in some districts.
I checked that the number of lead violations in my violations table matches those in NYC Open Data. I also checked that the number of buildings in my buildings table matches a count of the unique buildings with a lead violation in NYC Open Data.
Any tips on what I could be missing? I am wondering if maybe it could be the district maps themselves but I also exported a city council district map without simplifying it and the numbers were still off (though this was with estimated long lat coordinates for the buildings).
I found a way to use the NYC Geocoding API to retrieve the current assembly and state senate district for a building, but I really want to future proof this application and using spatial joining would be a much easier way to do that.
Any idea what I am missing? I know I should probably try again with a non-simplified map from map shaper, but I am just curious if I am wrong about my approach in general. I had another developer tell me he never uses spatial joins for how I am using because of inaccuracies.
Any insight?
Here is what my query looks like using city council district geometry.
SELECT
    count(v.*) as violations,
    count(DISTINCT b.*) as buildings_with_violations,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (v.building_id, v.apartment)) as units_with_violations,
    cd.councildistrict
    from council_districts as cd
    left join buildings as b on st_within(b.point, CASE 
        WHEN cd.geo_type = 'polygon' THEN cd.polygon
        WHEN cd.geo_type = 'multipolygon' THEN cd.multipolygon
    END)
    left join violations as v on v.building_id = b.nyc_open_data_building_id
    group by cd.councildistrict;


Well it turns out that NYC Open Data's geocoding for violation is outdate. The violations are based on the 2010 City Council District Map, not the 2020 one I am using.
So just a word of warning to anyone else coming across mismatched results when compared to NYC Open Data aggregation.
